# Rename directory hierarchy

Tags: directory, rename, directory-structure

How can I rename directory hierarchy?

For example I want to rename `c/d` to `x/y`
There won't be necessary only 2 folders.

So the full directory path `/a/b/c/d/e` becomes `/a/b/x/y/e` after the operation.

Not sure how to achieve it with pure bash (I assume the creation of such a bash script will take more time than I'll have to spent for manual renaming. I have ca. 200 such directories)

Maybe there is a utility for that purpose?

Comment: why not just `mv /a/b/c/d /a/b/c/y ; mv /a/b/c /a/b/x` ?  i.e. rename `d` to `y`, then rename `c` to `x`

Answer (score 0):

Via combining `mkdir -p` and `mv` it is pretty easy to do. The hard part (as always with shell) is to supply the names in a safe way in regards to special symbols which can be misinterpreted by the shell.

Let's say we can guarantee that the paths cannot contain `\t` and `\n` (which generally is NOT true for linux/unix system). Then we can supply a list of tab-separated fields to the renaming tool:

```bash
# Prepare paths
cat > names.txt <<"HERE" # TAB separated
a/b/c/d/file1   a/b/x/y/file1
a/white space/file2 a/c/z/while space/file2
a/fancy$name/file2  a/c/z/so what?/file2
HERE
# Do the renaming
while IFS=$'\t' read -r IN OUT; do
    printf 'Renaming [%s]->[%s]\n' "$IN" "$OUT"
    mkdir -p "${OUT%/*}"
    mv "$IN" "$OUT"
done < names.txt
```

Note: Of course, you can prepare the file `names.txt` using a text editor of your choice instead of `cat` and `here document` thing.

Note 2: `"${OUT%/*}"` syntax ("Remove matching suffix pattern") is bash-specific.

Note 3: old directories are not removed, you can run something like `find  -depth -type d -empty -print -exec rmdir {} \;` to get rid of those.

Comment: mkdir is not needed to rename directories.

Comment: @cas is wasn't specified by OP of the number of path elements would change or not, therefore simple renaming might not suffice. Also, there might be other files in those directories which shall not be affected.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many path elements there are, mkdir isn't needed for renaming them.   If there were particular files in some of the directories that needed to stay in the old directories, the OP would have / should have said so.  You've made an overly complicated script that doesn't actually do what the OP asked for (and the only slightly complicated thing about their task is that the directories need to be renamed in a depth-first manner so that, e.g. a/b/c isn't renamed before a/b/c/d...and maybe some collision checking if there's any risk of that)

Comment: Excuse me, how to rename a/b to v/w/z/y/z without mkdir?

Comment: just use `mv`.   no need at all for `mkdir`.